# Old Movie where a guy plays an electric guitar on the roof, and gets it played back

Tags: identify-this-movie

Ok, so I don't remember the movie's plot, but I've been getting these scenes for weeks in my head. I've tried google and everything but can't seem to find it, and no its not "**Crossroads**" nor "**Almost Famous**" ... I went to a point that I nearly convinced myself that I was imagining it until I saw this post http://whrl.pl/RdXg0R.

So I think the movie was filmed maybe in the 90's (of course in color and in English, maybe even American), and it goes like this:
a guy plays an electric guitar on the roof or on the balcony I can't quite remember, and a mysterious someone else (in the Neighborhood I think) plays back the licks that this character plays. This scene happens several times throughtout the movie until the main character plays a really hard lick using a beer bottle. And when he ends that lick, the whole neighborhood goes silent and that other mysterious player doesn't play back that last lick. Near the end of that movie, he finally meets that mysterious guitar player in a bar or something.

I really hope someone gets it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I watched the Crow and no that's not it but its a good call. thanks for trying though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sunset Strip (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178050/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)

> A day in Hollywood, 1972, with young people looking for the 24 hours that will change their lives. Zach will open that night for a British rocker at Whisky a Go-Go; he lives in a canyon and plays impromptu duets with a mysterious guitarist he doesn't see. Tammy is a costume designer, open to quick sex with the various rockers she works with and loved from afar by Michael, a photographer recovering from a case of the clap. His good friend is Felix, a morose, alcoholic songwriter. On hand for comic relief is Marty Shapiro, a fast-talking record producer. Getting ready for the gig at the club, Zach's performance, and the early-morning aftermath comprise the film.

[image]